# ProviderTestCase Test for Notification URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-testing

currently i write an Provider and the TestCase for it. It went well so far, and now im try to test if the notification works as expected. Basicly i create an ContentObserver and do an insert on my Observer. All Inserts working fine already i only struggle with the notification issue. For that i use an CountDownlatch in my ProviderTestCase which gets count down when any #onChange Method gets invoked:

```
@SmallTest
public void testUriNotification() throws Exception
{
    final TestContentObserver observer = new TestContentObserver(new Handler(), 1);
    resolver.registerContentObserver(FavoritesContract.Favorites.CONTENT_URI,true,observer);
    final ContentValues values = FavoritesContract.createFavorite(1);
    final Uri uri = resolver.insert(FavoritesContract.Favorites.CONTENT_URI, values);
    assertNotNull(uri);

    observer.latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertThat(observer.latch.getCount(), Matchers.is(0L));

    resolver.unregisterContentObserver(observer);
}

public static class TestContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public TestContentObserver(final Handler handler, final int countDown)
    {
        super(handler);
        latch = new CountDownLatch(countDown);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(final boolean selfChange)
    {
        latch.countDown();
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(final boolean selfChange, final Uri uri)
    {
        latch.countDown();
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    }
```

The insert Method is like this:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(final Uri uri, final ContentValues values)
{
    if (!insertAllowed(uri))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI:" + uri);
    }

    final SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

    if (isFavoriteItem(uri))
    {
        final long id = db.insert("favorites", null, values);
        return getUriForId(id, uri);
    }
    else if (isFavoriteList(uri))
    {
        final long id = db.insert("favorites", null, values);
        return getUriForId(id, uri);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching URI found for:" + uri);
}

private Uri getUriForId(long id, Uri uri)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getUriForId:"+id+" uri:"+uri);
    if (id > 0)
    {
        final Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
        if (!isInBatchMode())
        {
            // notify all listeners of changes and return itemUri:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Notify ContentResolver using :" + uri.toString());
            getContext().
                    getContentResolver().
                    notifyChange(itemUri, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cant notify ContentResolver, we are in Batch Mode for :" + uri.toString());
        }
        return itemUri;
    }
    return null;
}
private final boolean insertAllowed(final Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return ALLOWED_TYPES.contains(URI_MATCHER.match(uri));
}

private final boolean isFavoriteList(final Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return URI_MATCHER.match(uri) == FAVORITE_LIST;
}

private final boolean isFavoriteItem(final Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return URI_MATCHER.match(uri) == FAVORITE_ID;
}
```

So, the CountDownlatch will never be count down. I see that in the getUriForId Method the URI looks good. The URI end up the /ID of the Insert.

Im not sure if i created some kind of Deadlock there because the Latch waits and the provider cant invoke the Observer method using notifyChange Method. So after 5 Seconds the test fails because the timeout happened.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the Handler you create is bound to the test thread, therefore you'll never receive a callback. You'll need to use Looper.getMainLooper to get a reference to the main (thread) Handler:

```java
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Other recommendations, call observer.latch.await() before resolver.insert() to avoid a flaky test when the callback happens before your call to await().

Annotate this test with @MediumTest or @LargeTest. You should only use @SmallTest for unit tests.

Use assertTrue(observer.latch.getCount() <= 0) which is more readable in this case or if you want to stick to hamcrest Matchers, assertThat(observer.latch.getCount(), equalTo(0L));

Comment: I did that change:         final TestContentObserver observer = new TestContentObserver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), 1);  without any luck in called observer. Also i was raising an Exception in the Observer when it gets called to get better output in Logcat. No luck with this aproach

Comment: I read the Docs regarding the ProviderTestCase again. It used an MockContentResolver which seem to isolate the test from the system. That may the reason i cant test the notification.